# How can I extend the structure definition in patient profile in node-fhir-server-core

Tags: node-fhir-server-core, hl7-fhir

This issue is migrated from a question on our [Github account](https://github.com/Asymmetrik/node-fhir-server-core/) because we want the answer to be available to others. Here is the original question:

I need to add custom data field to patient FHIR object, There are any way to Extend structure definition in FHIR patient object in Asymmetrik/node-fhir-server-core

Answer (score 1):

Original answer provided by [Jon Lee](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11295033/jon-lee):

You can definitely add an extension to the Patient resource. The Patient Object extends the DomainResource which should give you access to the Extension Object.